# How to access and conditionally change css styles on a per element basis in typescript/nextjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, fullcalendar

I am using the FullCalendar library to create a work scheduler and am having difficulty isolating and changing the already dragged/created events' alignment properties. A feature I need is to be able to go in and individually change each event's alignment to either left or right. I am currently using a modal with buttons to do this, but have no clue how to implement the logic.

in `globals.css`

```
.fc-h-event {  /* To change event characteristics!!! */
  @apply bg-blue-500 border border-gray-600 text-left; 

}
```

Array of employees to be dragged onto calendar

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState([
  { title: "Employee 1", id: "1" },
  { title: "Employee 2", id: "2" },
  { title: "Employee 3", id: "3" },
  { title: "Employee 4", id: "4" },
  { title: "Employee 5", id: "5" },
  { title: "Employee 6", id: "6" },
  { title: "Employee 7", id: "7" },
  { title: "Employee 8", id: "8" },
]);
```

creates event when dragged onto calendar

```
useEffect(() => {
    let draggableEl = document.getElementById("draggable-el");
    if (draggableEl) {
      new Draggable(draggableEl, {
        itemSelector: ".fc-event",
        eventData: function (eventEl) {
          let title = eventEl.getAttribute("title");
          let id = eventEl.getAttribute("data");
          let start = eventEl.getAttribute("start");
          return { title, id, start };
        },
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

..... code in between

logic for draggable elements

```
<div
            id="draggable-el"
            className="ml-8 w-full border-2 p-2 rounded-md mt-16 lg:h-1/2 bg-violet-50"
          >
            <h1 className="font-bold text-lg text-center">Drag Employee</h1>
            {events.map((event) => (
              <div
                className={`fc-event border-2 p-1 m-2 w-full rounded-md ml-auto text-center bg-white`}
                title={event.title}
                key={event.id}
              >
                {event.title}
              </div>
            ))}
```